# How to add a column to DB with weight by using hook_update_N?

Tags: 7, database, hooks, updating

I want to add a column to a database by using hook_update_N(), but it should be 3rd column instead of last column. How I can achieve that please help in this regard. I tried to add **weight** but not working. below is my code which is creating a column at the last in the existed table.

```
function test_update_7001() {
  $column3 = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 256,
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'weight' => 3,
  );
  db_add_field('test_table', 'column3', $column3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db_add_field` doesn't support `AFTER`, which you would need to create your desired query.

You'll need to build an appropriate SQL string and run it through `db_query()` instead.